# PHP Random image not working

Tags: php, image, src

i want use php page(random image) in img src(`<img src="ads.php"/>`)

my **ads.php** page:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$img = array();
$img[] = '<img src="images/1.png" />';
$img[] = '<img src="images/2.png" />';
shuffle($img);
readfile ($img[0]);
?>
```

Comment: What exactly is "not working", you need to be more descriptive?

Comment: Can't understand your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values you put into your `$img` array need to be **pathnames to graphics**, not img tags.  When you're using `readfile()` it's trying to find `'<img src="images/1.png" />'` in the local filesystem.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$img = array();
//$img[] = '<img src="images/1.png" />';
//$img[] = '<img src="images/2.png" />';
$img[] = '/path/to/images/1.png';
$img[] = '/path/to/images/2.png';
shuffle($img);
readfile ($img[0]);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to out the image you have to use

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$img = array();
$img[] = '/path/to/images/1.png';
$img[] = '/path/to/images/2.png';
shuffle($img);
readfile ($img[0]);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider how the browser is seeing your code. It's parsing the page and encounters:

```
<img src="ads.php" />
```

and goes "ahah, I have to go hit the `ads.php` script on the site and it'll feed me an image". This is **NO** different than if you had

```
<img src="ads.jpg" />
```

The url you're telling the browser to hit on the server **MUST** serve up an **IMAGE**.

But instead of an image, you're serving up more html.

Comment: Just like "TVO", yours "Makes you think". Good answer.